# Uploading a file from memory to S3 with Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

This question has been asked many times, but my case is ever so slightly different. I'm trying to create a lambda that makes an .html file and uploads it to S3. It works when the file was created on disk, then I can upload it like so:

```
boto3.client('s3').upload_file('index.html', bucket_name, 'folder/index.html')
```

So now I have to create the file in memory, for this I first tried [StringIO()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO). However then `.upload_file` throws an error.

```
boto3.client('s3').upload_file(temp_file, bucket_name, 'folder/index.html')
ValueError: Filename must be a string`.
```

So I tried using `.upload_fileobj()` but then I get the error `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

So I tried using [Bytesio()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) which wants me to convert the str to bytes first, so I did:

```
temp_file = BytesIO()
temp_file.write(index_top.encode('utf-8'))
print(temp_file.getvalue())
boto3.client('s3').upload_file(temp_file, bucket_name, 'folder/index.html')
```

But now it just uploads an empty file, despite the `.getvalue()` clearly showing that it does have content in there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you wish to create an object in Amazon S3 from memory, use [`put_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object):

```py
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

html = "<h2>Hello World</h2>"

s3_client.put_object(Body=html, Bucket='my-bucket', Key='foo.html', ContentType='text/html')
```

Comment: That was so much simpler than I had thought. It didn't even need the whole StringIO() nonsense.

Answer (score 8):

> But now it just uploads an empty file, despite the .getvalue() clearly >showing that it does have content in there.

When you finish writing to a file buffer, the position stays at the end. When you upload a buffer, it starts from the position it is currently in. Since you're at the end, you get no data. To fix this, you just need to add a seek(0) to reset the buffer back to the beginning after you finish writing to it. Your code would look like this:

```
temp_file = BytesIO()
temp_file.write(index_top.encode('utf-8'))
temp_file.seek(0)
print(temp_file.getvalue())
boto3.client('s3').upload_file(temp_file, bucket_name, 'folder/index.html')
```

Comment: Note that in the case where you already have the string, you can pass it into the `BytesIO` constructor directly, which will create the buffer with the given data but leave the position at 0, saving you from typing all of those letters in the `seek` call.  (This won't work if you're building the bytes buffer incrementally over several calls to `write`, of course.)

Comment: In terms of performances and stability, this solution is *much* better than the other one: `upload_file` uses [multipart upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html), that `put_object` doesn't.

Comment: I changed it to "upload_fileobj" and it worked like a charm