error lambda aws function processing images to save to S3
I am having an error that I can't solve when sending an image through postman to an api that I have created in AWS, I process the request in a lambda function and to read the content of the image I decode it in base64 to later save it in a bucket of s3 with the following code:

def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    
    img_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
  
    # Guarda la imagen en un archivo temporal
    aux_path = '/tmp/{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    with open(aux_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data)
        
    # Sube la imagen a S3
    bucket = 'mys3'
    s3_key = '{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    s3.upload_file(aux_path, bucket, s3_key)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200, 
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'file saved successfully'}), 
        'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    }

The problem is that when decoding the image I get the following error:
[ERROR] ValueError: string argument should contain only ASCII characters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 16, in lambda_handler
    img_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/base64.py", line 83, in b64decode
    s = _bytes_from_decode_data(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/base64.py", line 39, in _bytes_from_decode_data
    raise ValueError('string argument should contain only ASCII characters')

In the API configuration I have added as binary media type / so there should not be the problem.
Any suggestions ? Thank you very much
I am trying to save an image in s3 with a lambda function. I am sending the image through postaman to an api created in aws.
Here the post request:
post request that I´m sending to the API

Can you please try decoding in utf-8. I guess your issue will be solved.

how should I decode in utf8 ?

What exactly does event['body'] contain…?

The information of the request and I´m just sending an image in binary format through postman in the request

An actual sample would help…

I have just added an actual sample as postman screenshot

You don't need a temp file - you can upload the bytes directly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69226086/1021819

If I upload the bytes directly I´m not able to see the image in the s3, is not saved correctly

@TomSmiths Are you remembering to first rewind the file object via my_obj.seek(0)?

The error is being thrown because you are writing the encoded base64 image to the file system instead of the decoded version of it.
def lambda_handler(event, context):    
    
    img_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
  
    # Guarda la imagen en un archivo temporal
    aux_path = '/tmp/{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    with open(aux_path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img_data) # What fixes your problem ^_^
        
    # Sube la imagen a S3
    bucket = 'mys3'
    s3_key = '{}.jpg'.format(generate_unique_id())
    s3.upload_file(aux_path, bucket, s3_key)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200, 
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'file saved successfully'}), 
        'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
    }


Hi dude, thanks for your answer. You´re right that it should be like that but the problem is happening in:  img_data = base64.b64decode(event['body'])

@TomSmiths, show me how did you guys encoded the base64 image in the client side. The client-side code for encoding it will give me hints on how to fix this

In the client side is done automatically by postman. I have attached an image of the request that I´m sending to the API

@TomSmiths, thanks for sharing it. Do you have any insights on how huge is the jpg file?

like 50 KB but the image should not be the problem, I have tried with different images
